# Can a dictionary be passed to django models on create?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Is it possible to do something similar to this with a `list`, `dictionary` or something else?

```
data_dict = {
    'title' : 'awesome title',
    'body' : 'great body of text',
}

Model.objects.create(data_dict)
```

Even better if I can extend it:

```
Model.objects.create(data_dict, extra='hello', extra2='world')
```

Answer (score 287, accepted):

If `title` and `body` are fields in your model, then [you can deliver the keyword arguments in your dictionary using the ** operator](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Assuming your model is called `MyModel`:

```
# create instance of model
m = MyModel(**data_dict)
# don't forget to save to database!
m.save()
```

As for your second question, the dictionary has to be the final argument. Again, `extra` and `extra2` should be fields in the model.

```
m2 =MyModel(extra='hello', extra2='world', **data_dict)
m2.save()
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking to do. Also, as a side note just based off your post. You don't have to call the save method when using Model.objects.create(**data_dict). You probably already know this but just a heads up.

Comment: I've not used the `objects.create` method before, so you've taught me something new.

Comment: also objects.create returns a pointer to the new model, with a valid pk filled in. This means you can immediately use it to build related models.

Comment: I got bit by `ForeignKey`s. If your model has a `ForeignKey` called `owner`, then your `data_dict` should have an `owner_id` field. But `django.forms.model_to_dict()` returns a dict with an `owner` field. So you can't do `MyModel(**model_to_dict(my_instance))`; you have to rename the `owner` field to `owner_id`.

Comment: The foreign key thing (adding _id) didn't work for me with 1.5.4.  I had to do something more like modelinstance.save(),  modelinstance.add(foreignobject.id) for a MTM relation.  Thanks though.  This really helped me get on the right track to getting it working.

Comment: That is a good point about model_to_dict naming of keys.  I use __dict__ of a model (m2.__dict__, the keys are named correctly and it doesn't add the extra stuff you may/maynot want.  Note there are some hidden fields you'll want to remove, they all start wtih an _

Comment: @PaulvonHoesslin you’re more likely to get an answer if you ask a new question and include code to reproduce the issue

Comment: In Django 4. x, No need for m.sasve() anymore. It will return a tuple,  `obj, is_created = Model.objects.get_or_create(**dic)`

Comment: @bobopei `Model.objects.create(**data_dict)` would probably be better. I would only use `get_or_create` if I expected there would be duplicates and needed to handle them.

Answer (score 2):

For any model `DummyModel` you can use `DummyModel.objects.create(**data_dict)`. Does not require save after the create.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly an answer to the question, but I find this code helped me create the dicts that save nicely into the correct answer.  The type conversions made are required if this data will be exported to json.

I hope this helps:

```
  #mod is a django database model instance
def toDict( mod ):
  import datetime
  from decimal import Decimal
  import re

    #Go through the object, load in the objects we want
  obj = {}
  for key in mod.__dict__:
    if re.search('^_', key):
      continue

      #Copy my data
    if isinstance( mod.__dict__[key], datetime.datetime ):
      obj[key] = int(calendar.timegm( ts.utctimetuple(mod.__dict__[key])))
    elif isinstance( mod.__dict__[key], Decimal ):
      obj[key] = float( mod.__dict__[key] )
    else:
      obj[key] = mod.__dict__[key]

  return obj 

def toCsv( mod, fields, delim=',' ):
  import datetime
  from decimal import Decimal

    #Dump the items
  raw = []
  for key in fields:
    if key not in mod.__dict__:
      continue

      #Copy my data
    if isinstance( mod.__dict__[key], datetime.datetime ):
      raw.append( str(calendar.timegm( ts.utctimetuple(mod.__dict__[key]))) )
    elif isinstance( mod.__dict__[key], Decimal ):
      raw.append( str(float( mod.__dict__[key] )))
    else:
      raw.append( str(mod.__dict__[key]) )

  return delim.join( raw )
```