# Is it possible to pass a dictionary with extraneous elements to a Django object.create method?

Tags: python, django, django-models, dictionary

I am aware that when using MyModel.objects.create in Django, it is possible to pass in a dictionary with keys which correspond to the model fields in MyModel. This is explained in another question here: [Can a dictionary be passed to django models on create?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571570/can-a-dictionary-be-passed-to-django-models-on-create)

However, I am trying to pass in a dictionary which has more keys than there are model fields - in other words, some of the keys are not used in the creation of the object. Is it possible to do this in some way? For example:

```
data_dict = {
    'key1': value1,
    'key2': value2,
    'key3': value3,
}

class MyModel(models.Model):
    key1 = models.SomeField()
    key2 = models.SomeField()

m = MyModel.objects.create(**data_dict)
```

When I try this, I get an error telling me that "'key3' is an invalid keyword argument for this function". Am I passing the dictionary in incorrectly? Is there a different way to pass it to the model that means the model doesn't have to use all of the arguments? Or will I simply have to specify each field manually like this:

```
m = MyModel.objects.create(
    key1 = data_dict['key1'],
    key2 = data_dict['key2'],
)
```

Comment: u have to specify each field manually .

Comment: you can specify less but not more

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can filter, then pass your dictionary this way:

`MyModel.objects.create(**{key: value for key, value in data_dict.iteritems() if key in MyModel._meta.get_all_field_names()})`.

Comment: 2.7 only. Before that you'd need to do `**dict((key, value) for...)`

Comment: in python3+ use `dict.items()` instead of `dict.iteritems()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418481/error-dict-object-has-no-attribute-iteritems