# sqlalchemy - save multiple values at once

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In `sqlalchemy` I have a base class `Stock`.
Now I'd like to bind some previously scraped items and want to bind them like so:

```
stock = Stock(isin = item['isin'], name = item['name'], points = item['points'], ...)
```

This feels very unpythonic and boring.
The keys from `item` are named exactly like the internal representation of `Stock`, however some items need to be ignored (these start with an underscore, e.g. `item['_leave_me_alone']`).
Is there a way to write the above in a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could adapt the method used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798606/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-dictionary-with-extraneous-elements-to-a-django-object), or in other words unpack a filtered dict as arguments:

```
stock = Stock(**{k: v for k, v in item.items() if not k.startswith('_')})
```