# Model create using dictionary in django

Tags: python, django

In Django is it possible to create through dictionary similar as to filtering?

Here is my models.py:

```
class Personnels(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Here is my views.py:

```
from . models import *

def artists(request):
    personnels = Personnels.objects.all()

    if request.method == "POST":
            data = {"name": "Dean Armada"}
            Personnels.objects.create(data)
```

However the code above will throw an error. What I really am trying to do is to do a create function coming from a "request.POST" but my views above serves as a simple example on doing it

Comment: `Personnels.objects.create(**data)`

Comment: Crap I forgot about the two asterisk! Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a dictionary be passed to django models on create?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571570/can-a-dictionary-be-passed-to-django-models-on-create)

Answer (score 6):

Simply unwrap the dictionary within `create` function like:

```
Personnels.objects.create(**data)
```

Comment: i am facing the problem when i used this due to presence of a foreign key https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69349618/trying-to-save-dict-in-my-model-but-getting-error-due-to-foreign-key/69355144#69355144