# Object of type leave is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

{i am unable to get how to resolve this problem.i am trying to save a dict buy creating a model instance but i am  getting error due to the foreign key in my leave model which is connected to hostel manager through one to many relation }

i have resolved this error but got new error Object of type leave is not JSON serializable i do not how to resolve this

and in my database the data i obtain through request is getting saved but the data which i got from other table by using `jwt` token  is not getting saved

```
final_data= leave(**serializer)
```

views.py

```
class leaveview(APIView):
    def post(self,request):
        token = request.data['jwt']
        if not token:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Unauthenticated')
        
        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(token,'secret',algorithms=['HS256'])
        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Unauthenticated')
        
        user=User.objects.filter(id=payload['id']).first()
        serializer1=UserSerializers(user).data


        serializer2 = leaveSerializers(data=request.data)
        serializer2.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer={**serializer1,**request.data}
        
        del serializer["jwt"]
        loc = hostel_manager.objects.get(hostel = serializer['hostel_name'])
        del serializer['hostel_name']
        del serializer['password']
        a=leave.objects.create(**serializer,**{'hostel_name' : loc} )
        
        
        a=leaveSerializers(a)
        return Response(a.data)
```

models.py

```
class hostel_manager(models.Model):
    hostel = models.CharField(max_length=100,primary_key=True)


class leave(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100,null = True)
    father_name=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    
    
    branch=models.CharField(max_length=40,null=True)
    coer_id=models.CharField(max_length=12,unique=True,null=True)
    
    hostel_name = models.ForeignKey(hostel_manager,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    room_no = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    where_to = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    reason = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    start_date = models.CharField(max_length = 100,null=True)
    end_date = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    phone_regex=RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+9999999999'. Up to 12 digits allowed.")
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17)
```

this is the error i got

```
  File "d:\python\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type leave is not JSON serializable
```

serializer.py

```
class leaveSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = leave
        fields = ['id','hostel_name','room_no','where_to','reason','phone_number','start_date','end_date','name','father_name','branch','coer_id']


class hostelmanagerSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = hostel_manager
        fields = ['hostel']
```

Comment: Can you show the error ?

Comment: ```leave.objects.create(**serializer,hostel_name_id=serializer['id'])``` i tried this too by giving an id but this also gave the same error

Comment: finally i have solved my errors thanks everyone and special thanks to rvector and chris for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error message suggests that you are trying to assign `hostel_name` as a string/CharField. As per your model, it needs to be a `hostel_manager` object.

Not sure what your POST serializer or payload looks like but you'd probably want to set the `hostel_manager_pk` field to the kund kund bhawan's object's PK.

Comment: ```serializer = {'id': 1, 'name': 'Manoj kumar', 'father_name': 'Ashok kumar', 'branch': 'CSE', 'coer_id': '18041055', 'phone_number': '9212115634', 'hostel_name': 'kund kund bhawan', 'room_no': '322', 'where_to': 'roorkee', 'reason': 'nothing', 'start_date': 'gog', 'end_date': '23'} ```when i try to unwrap this by creating a leave model instance this error show up

Comment: i used ```leave.objects.create(**serializer)``` but this also gave similar error .

Comment: Your issue is in the `serialized data` near `'hostel_name': 'kund kund bhawan',`. You define `hostel_name` in your model as a `ForeignKey` to `hostel_manager` model. Then you must pass an `id` of this model instance. **Try with :** `hostel_id = hostel_manager.objects.first().id`. And in the serializer `'hostael_name': hostel_id`. It should work

Comment: ```id``` field does not exist in my ```hostel_manager``` model so it give me an error.I tried to add a ```id ``` field to my table before also but it does not allow it.

Comment: thanks ```Rvector``` for the advice it worked put got another error