# How to load json data with get_or_create?

Tags: python, json, django

I am a programming self-learner and I am new to python and django and would like to optimize my code.

My problem is that I want to do a get_or_create with some loaded json data. Each dictionary entry is directly linked to my model. example:

```
data=json.load(file)
Person.objects.get_or_create(
    firstname=data['firstname'],
    surname=data['surname'],
    gender=data['gender'],
    datebirth=data['datebirth'],
)
```

Are there any ways to automatically link the json properties to my model fields instead of typing all my properties one by one?

Comment: Instead, I would suggest please consider clean the values before to insert in DB. seems like premature optimization to me

Answer (score 1):

What you might want to do is to unpack your list of arguments. [Link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) to Python docs.

Say your model is Person:

```py
p = Person(**data_dict)
p.save()
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1571593)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write following code in python shell:

```
import json
data = json.loads(source)
print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```