# How to save json data in Django database using queryset

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, templates

I have this json data

```
{
    'items_data': [
        {'item': 'Datalogger', 'hsn': '123', 'unit_name': 'BAG', 'unit_price': '100', 'quantity': '4',
         'tax_code': 'GST 18', 'base_discount': '4', 'discount_value': 16, 'amount': 384, 'state': 'Maharashtra',
         'invoice_number': 'TES-0822-97', 'tax_no': '18', 'tax_name': 'GST', 'base_Amount': 400, 'CGST': 36, 'SGST': 36}, 

        {'item': 'Datalogger', 'hsn': '123', 'unit_name': 'BAG', 'unit_price': '100', 'quantity': '4', 
         'tax_code': 'GST 28', 'base_discount': '4', 'discount_value': 16, 'amount': 384, 'state': 'Maharashtra',
         'invoice_number': 'TES-0822-97', 'tax_no': '28', 'tax_name': 'GST', 'base_Amount': 400, 'CGST': 56, 'SGST': 56}],

 'invoice_num': 'TES-0822-97',

 'gst_data': [
    {'tax_no': '18', 'totalGST': 72, 'total_base_amount': 400, 'cgst': 36, 'sgst': 36},
    {'tax_no': '28', 'totalGST': 112, 'total_base_amount': 400, 'cgst': 56, 'sgst': 56}
  ]
}
```

Now I want to get items data and store into database by query set. how can I save this by using query set objects?

I am doing this code

```
def get_invoice_items(request):

json_body = json.loads(request.body)
print(json_body)
for data in json_body["items_data"]:
    print(data)
    items=Items_Details.objects.bulk_create(data)
    print(items)

return JsonResponse({"message" : "Request Handled.."})
```

but getting error

Comment: Can you tell us what error are you getting?

Comment: Use DjangoRestFramework.

Comment: Tried to update field sales.Items_Details.sales_invoice_id with a model instance, <Sales_Invoice: Sales_Invoice object (131)>. Use a value compatible with CharField.

Answer (score 0):

`bulk_create` requires objects' list as the first argument. Try the following

```
    items = []
    for data in json_body["items_data"]:
        # create item objects through django rest framework deserialization.
        # or 
        items.append(Item_Details(**data))
    Item_Details.objects.bulk_create(items)
```

PS: This would only work if all the fields in data dict are fields in the model.
[Can a dictionary be passed to django models on create?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571570/can-a-dictionary-be-passed-to-django-models-on-create)

Comment: I need to add fields of json in my database

Comment: Do you mean you want to create the fields in your json in your database? You shouldn't dynamically create fields in django. You should show what your item_details model looks like.

Comment: yes I am sorting my data from items_details which  I want and then then I am passing that data on method POST

Comment: You need to declare fields of the model in you Item_Details model, it should contain all the fields that you might expect in json.